# Body of Email using Visual force Email templare is missing in email

Tags: apex, visual

I am using a visualforce email template from Apex Batch class. I am getting the Body of email when checking from Preview and Test mode. But if I schedule the batch, only blank email is coming. I am using visualforce component with custom controller  inside my visualforce email template to prepare the email body.

Below is the code.

Email Template:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Pending Letter" recipientType="Contact" 
 relatedToType="Return__c">
  <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <c:Pending_Letter caseId="{!relatedTo.Case__r.Id}" contactId={!relatedTo.Case__r.Contact.Id}"/>
  </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Vf Component:

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="Reminder_Letter">
<apex:attribute name="contactId" type="Id" description="Id of the Contact" assignTo="{!contact}"/>
<apex:attribute name="caseId" type="Id" description="Id of the Case" assignTo="{!cId}"/>  
 <apex:dataTable value="{!returnList}" var="pr" id="dtCaseInfo"
                 rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass">
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header"> Serial Number  </apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!pr.Issue__r.SerialNumber__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    </apex:dataTable>  
   OTHER MY HARDCODED TEXT FOR EMAIL BODY  
 </apex:component>
```

Controller:

```
public class Reminder_Letter {
public Id cId {get;set;}
public Id contact {get;set;}
List<Return__c> productReturnList;
Public List<Return__c> getReturnList(){            

   if(cId != null) {
       ReturnList = new List<Return__c>([Select   Id, Name,Return_Status__c, Issue__r.Serial_Number__c FROM  Return__c WHERE Return_Status__c  IN ('Pending') AND Case__c =: cId]);
       return ReturnList;
   }
   return null;
 } 
}
```

Batch Class Code (for sending mail) :
I am referring the VF email template using the following line. As the batch is working fine only sharing the portion related to email functionality.

```
 EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE developerName = 'Reminder_Letter'];
```

==============================

```
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String [] toaddress = toStr;
    EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE developerName = 'Reminder_Letter'];
    mail.setTargetObjectId(tgtObjId); 
    mail.setWhatId(prId);
    mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);
    mail.setToAddresses(toaddress);
    mail.setSubject('Test email');

    try{         
        results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});   
    }
    Catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('e'+e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: share your btach class code also. May be you are not passing correct parameters.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma - i am not sure how to pass parameters to vf template from batch.

Comment: Thats why I asked you to share your batch code?

Comment: @TusharSharma: added it. Please check

Comment: @TusharSharma- I am now adding custom setting to the component's construtor but it is not loading values. Could you please check?

Comment: @TusharSharma - Posted https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171178/problem-in-accessing-custom-settings-value-from-visual-force-component-for-dynam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using Email template so you need to remove this line

```
mail.setSubject('Test email');
```

It will override your template. So remove this line and you will get email body.

Comment: You rock !! it's working..

Comment: I am now using custom setting to load mail body as per country settings and there It's not working as expected. Could you please check?

Comment: @CRMGuy post it as separate question and tag me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override only email subject not body, you can render your SingleEmailMessage like

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, whoId, whatId);
message.setSubject('Test email');
```