# Problem in accessing custom settings value from Visual Force Component for dynamic email body generation

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using a visualforce email template from Apex Batch class.That visual forc template is using a component for email body generation. Now, I am using custom setting(type list) to get dynamic email body based on country. But I am unable to access the custom settings field value(line1__c, line2__c etc from below code) from either constructor or getter setter.

Please note, when I am using harcoded text instead of custom settings field, the email works absolutely fine.

Below is the code.

Email Template:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Pending Letter" recipientType="Contact" 
 relatedToType="Return__c">
  <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <c:Pending_Letter caseId="{!relatedTo.Case__r.Id}" contactId={!relatedTo.Case__r.Contact.Id}"/>
  </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Vf Component:

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="Reminder_Letter">
<apex:attribute name="contactId" type="Id" description="Id of the Contact" assignTo="{!contact}"/>
<apex:attribute name="caseId" type="Id" description="Id of the Case" assignTo="{!cId}"/>  
 {!customSettings.Line1__c} <br/>
 {!customSettings.Line2__c}
 <apex:dataTable value="{!returnList}" var="pr" id="dtCaseInfo"
                 rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass">
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header"> Serial Number  </apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!pr.Issue__r.SerialNumber__c}"/>
    </apex:column>
    </apex:dataTable>  
   {!customSettings.Line3__c}
   <br/>
   <br/>
    {!customSettings.Line4__c}
 </apex:component>
```

Controller:

```
public class ADC_Ctrl_Reminder_Letter { 
public Id cId {get;set;}
public Id contact {get;set;}
//customSettings
Reminder_Letter__c customSettings{get;set;}


List<Product_Return__c> ReturnList;

public ADC_Ctrl_Reminder_Letter(){
    customSettings = Reminder_Letter__c.getInstance('USA');
}

//List to be used in VF
Public List<Product_Return__c> getReturnList(){
   if(cId != null) {
       productReturnList = new List<Product_Return__c>([Select  
                                                        Id, Name,Return_Status__c, Case__c, Issue__c
                                                        FROM 
                                                        Return__c 
                                                        WHERE Return_Status__c  IN ('Pending')
                                                        AND Case__c =: cId] );
       return ReturnList;
   }
   return null;
  } 
}
```

Comment: @TusharSharma- Posted it here.Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have to declare `customSettings` as `public` access modifier to use it in visualforce page.

**Wrong code** (without access modifier, that is default access in controller).

```
Reminder_Letter__c customSettings{get;set;}
```

**Correct Code**

```
public Reminder_Letter__c customSettings{get;set;}

List<Reminder_Letter__c> reminderLetterSettings = Reminder_Letter__c.getall().values();

//check for which attribute you are comparing with 'USA'
if (reminderLetterSettings[0].<attrbiute api> == 'USA') {
  customSettings = reminderLetterSettings[0];
}
```

For more information, refer [Accessing Custom Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cs_accessing.htm&language=en&type=0)

Comment: Corrected. Its a typo while posting here...But still my problem persists.

Comment: same result with get values and getInstance.. :( . this is a public list type custom settings

Comment: can you use public access modifier, public Reminder_Letter__c customSettings{get;set;}

Comment: Ohh yes..you are correct...thank you.... Not sure why I make the same mistake again n again..